# Not able to run hello world prog in phonegap

Tags: android, iphone, cordova

I m new to phonegap.So i was trying to run Hello world html file in android emulator which comes with phonegap.But i m getting this error

**Application Error 
There was a network error.(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)**

I checked HTML file by clicking run with browser in eclipse and its running good.But when it comes to run as Android application then it is giving error.
Before posting this question i Googled for solutions and there i got to know that we should enable permission for internet,but it is also done and also LAN is disabled as some one stated in this website as solution.And also i got to know that its problem with Android SDK and every phonegap user facing this problem.Is that true??

I m really good at HTML,CSS and Javascript.So i opt phonegap.But now i m very sad.

Last question.Will it give same problem if i use XCode for iPhone in Phonegap??

Regards
Devaraju

Comment: Have you tried following this guide? [PhoneGap - Getting started](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android)

Comment: Yeah i checked this one and did exactly what they said..But not working..

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this permission too.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: but again same problem.I enabled USB Debugging also and tried to run in Android mobile.But its showing nothing. please somone help me..

Comment: Edited my answer. Try adding every permission phonegap states, if still doesn't work, like WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, GET_ACCOUNTS...

Answer (score 0):

This network error shows up for various reasons, but my guess is that your config.xml is looking for index.html and you have named your html page something else.